# How to close custom positioned PopupMenu in delphi?

Tags: delphi, popup

I have a project with `CoolTrayIcon` and `PopupMenu` with disabled `AutoPopup` property.
I would like to position the PopupMenu and show it for the user.
The position is OK but menu doesn't close if the user clicks away or press ESC button.
I have not found any property like `Active` which could help if the menu is used or not.

Here I position the menu:

```
procedure TForm1.CoolTrayIcon1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  pnt: TPoint; yy:integer;
begin

GetCursorPos(pnt);
yy:=pnt.y; yy:=yy-500;

if (Button=mbRight) then begin
    PopupMenu1.Popup(pnt.X, yy);
end;

end;
```

How could I manage to close menu if it is needed?

Comment: What happens if the user tries to use the keyboard to show the menu?

Comment: Menu should open with clicking with the right click that's OK, but how could close? :D

Comment: Context menus should be opened when the user asks for them. Perhaps by clicking the right mouse button. Or perhaps by using the keyboard. That key to the left of your right hand CTRL key.

Comment: Clicking the right mouse button. Idk what happens if the user tries to use the keyboard but I will check that out.

Comment: The right way to handle this is to listen for `WM_CONTEXTMENU` in the code that handles the messages for the notification icon. The system does the heavy lifting and converts the appropriate user input into that message. The details are a little hazy because of the different versions of notification icon. And I've no idea what this particular component does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue that is discussed here:

[PRB: Menus for Notification Icons Do Not Work Correctly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135788)

You need to wrap the call to `Popup()` as follows:

```
SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
PopupMenu1.Popup(pnt.X, yy);
PostMessage(Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
```

In this code, `Handle` is the window handle of the form associated with the notification icon.

Comment: For me it's not working. Indeed, the menu cand be closed with Esc key but after I popup the menu, my application is completely dead, I can't access anything on the main form. I mention that my tray icons HWND is a private one, not the HWND of the main form.

Comment: Works fine here. And there are countless examples of other posts and other code doing just this. So I guess you either did something wrong, or there is some important detail missing.

Comment: It might be because I execute this (popup wraped) code in the WndProc of the Handle I use ?

Comment: It might be. Very difficult to tell from here.